# Android Custom Scheme with Numeric Parameters

Tags: android, android-intent, url-scheme

I'm trying to pass a numeric ID by using a custom scheme on Android.

My intent filter is defined in AndroidManifest as follows:

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="foo" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Links in this form work:

- foo://bar/baz?id=text

But when I try to use a numeric parameter, it fails:

- foo://bar/baz?id=123

How can I set up the intent filter so that I can send numeric querystring parameters?

Comment: Try adding `android:pathPattern` into your `data` tag, `"android:pathPattern="/bar/baz?id=*"`

Comment: What do you mean by _"it fails"_?

Comment: The intent extras have the path, even the querystring parameter, but not the appended id. e.g. "foo://bar/baz?id="